# SQL - Remove all duplicates and retain just one

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like below

```
Order_Id (PK), Customer_ID, Order_Amount
  A01             AA01         100
  A01             AA01         100 (duplicate)
  A02             AA01         200
  A03             AA02         300
```

I want to remove the duplicate and retain the remaining one

I'm able to select the duplicate using below

```
select *
from 
(
select order_id, customer_id, order_amount, row_number () over (partition by order_id order by order_Id) as rnk
from mytable
) where rnk > 1
```

But what's the next step to delete this record from mytable? Do I need to create a interim table?

Thanks!

Comment: `order_id` is NOT a primary key if it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Redshift has a way to identify rows, if all the data is the same.  So, I think your best bet is to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_mytable as
    select distinct *
    from mytable;

truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable
    select *
    from distinct mytable;
```

If your table really did have a primary key, there would be alternative ways of deleting rows.

Comment: +1! Last insert should be `insert into mytable select * from temp_mytable;`. Also would be good idea to clean up `drop table temp_mytable` :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be works.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
     order_id, 
     customer_id, 
     order_amount, 
     row_number () OVER (partition by order_id order by order_Id) as rnk
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY order_id
) WHERE rnk > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query below it should work as your requirements,

```
delete from CUSTOMER
where rowid not in
(select max(rowid) from CUSTOMER group by order_amount);
```